# Laravel - Validate inside Controller without make CustomRequest

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I would like to validate the get parameter where i passed throug the route to my controller.

**api/route**

get /order/{id} -> OrderController::order

```
public function order($id) {
 // validation here (rules= require,between 1 and 1000)
  return Order::find($id);
}
```

1. how can I validate inside my controller without creating a separate request class?
2. which validation class do i have to import? (this one: Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator ? )
3. Is this a good or common solution?

Comment: you can use the regular Request itself to do the validation ... https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic ... or, you can manually create them https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#manually-creating-validators

Comment: Both solutions are a good solution, I like the custom request class to make the controller functions shorter. as Lagbox commented its not needed to include a class.

Comment: @lagbox Hey! Yes that will work when i will validate my request. but take a look to the parameterlist of my order funtion. i get the $id from the GET route. or am I wrong here?

Comment: route parameters are not part of the inputs ... so you would have to merge that into the inputs to use `$request->validate(....)` with that, or do the manual validation where you are defining the data to be validated ... though do you need to validate that route parameter at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @lagbox already wrote, you can check all of your questions inside the Laravel documentation.

**Validation inside the controller**

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function order(Request $request, int $id)
    {
      $validated = $this->validate([
          // .. put your fields and rules here
      ]);
    }
}
```

If your controller extends the [base controller](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php), that is shipped with every Laravel installation you have direct access to the validator via `$this->validate`.

With injecting the `$request` you have access to the fields that are send (`POST`ed) to your server.

If this is a good solution heavily depends on the projects size and other factors. It is definitely a good solution to start with. If your project grows and you need to have the same validation logic in various places you can again think about additional [Form Request Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation).

To apply certain rules to the route parameter, f. ex. `id`, you can use [Regular Expression Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints).

**Futher processing of request data**

I personally would leave the validation inside the controller (or a form request class).
If there is any problem with the request data, then it should fail there and not continue to the service class.

You could say this is a kind of `fail fast` approach. Why moving more and more inside your code, if your request items might have an error (are not valid)?

Comment: the controller helper `validate` only takes a Request unfortunately, would be nice if it would take a data array as well

Comment: @codedge It sounds good! One more question. I pass from my OrderController the Request and $id to my OrderService. To have access to the validate Function i have to extend my OrderService with Controller, right? My Question: is this an elegant solution or would you do something different?

Comment: @MaikLowrey I updated my post. To me it doesn't make sense to move this into your service. Just a personal note without knowing all of your project details.

Answer (score 2):

`$id` is always present so `required` validation always passes.
So you only need to check `between 1 and 1000` condition.
I think using [regex constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints) in the route is a good idea here.

```
Route::get('/order/{id}','OrderController@order')
    ->where(['id'=> '1000|^[1-9]{0,2}[1-9]$']);
```

If `id` is less than 1 or more than 1000 or any other random string it won't match the route and if there isn't any other matching routes too, it gives 404 error.

If you really want to validate the route parameter in the controller, you can use this:

```
$validator = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::make(['id' => $id],
    [
        'id' => 'required|integer|between:1,1000'
    ]
);
$validator->validate();
```

Comment: cool answear! I implement it and if i try to pass an id over 1000 that laravel redirect my to my index route / (start page). Why i dont get any response from the validation like the number is not between 1 and 1000?

Comment: I found out for the api call! i have to put to my request header Accept = application/json. then i became a json with error messages. but if i try over the web route i donbt recieve error messages.

Comment: @MaikLowrey because validation exceptions cause a redirect "back" (if it can't determine what "back" is it defaults to `/`) with errors and inputs (when not telling the server that you accept JSON), so that view that is returned from the route you redirected to would have to handle displaying any error messages ... when you say you accept JSON you just get the JSON